# Documentar el código Google script app

Tags: google-apps-script, jsdoc

Quisiera saber si en el editor de Google Apps Scripts hay alguna forma de que genere la documentación básica de las funciones que escribo como si pasa en otros IDE.

Lo que quiero es que cuando tengo una función, como por ejemplo:

```js
function miFuncion(param1,param2,param3, ..., paramN){
...
return variableRetorno
}
```

hacer algo para que el editor, de forma automática me añada algo parecido a:

```js
/**
  * @Param1
  * @Param2
  * @Param3
  * ...
  * @ParamN
  *
  * @return variableRetorno
*/
function miFuncion(param1,param2,param3, ..., paramN){
...
return variableRetorno
}
```

Y a partir de ahí, yo pueda completar los comentarios sobre los parámetros de la función.

Supongo que existe algo pero no he podido encontrar como hacerlo.
De no existir, creo que es algo sencillo de implementar e incorporar al editor por parte de Google.

Answer (score 0):

El editor de Google Apps Script no incluye la generación automática. Para solventar esta deficiencia puedes recurrir a otro IDE que ofrezca dicha funcionalidad para JavaScript.

P.D. Las sugerencias al equipo a cargo de Google Apps Script se plantean en el "Issue Tracker". Los detalles en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features

Comment: Grácias rubén por tu ayuda